# @DeclareMixin not being called on SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj

I'm trying to use `@DeclareMixin` to add a common behavior in some classes, but I couldn't make it work.

I've created a simple example [here](https://github.com/finxster/declare-mixin-example), if you want to reproduce just run `ExampleResourceTest`.

My interface:

```
public interface ExampleInterface {
  String world();
}
```

Default implementation:

```
public class ExampleInterfaceImpl implements ExampleInterface {
  @Override
  public String world() {
    return " world!";
  }
}
```

Aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ExampleAspect {

  @DeclareMixin(value = "com.example.service.* *")
  public ExampleInterface exampleInterface() {
    return new ExampleInterfaceImpl();
  }
}
```

The service that should receive the ExampleInterface's behavior:

```
package com.example.demo.service;

@Service
@ExampleAnnotation
public class ExampleService {

  @ExampleAnnotation
  public String hello() {
    String output = "Hello";
    if (this instanceof ExampleInterface) {
      output += ((ExampleInterface) this).world();
    }
    return output;
  }

}
```

The expected behavior should return "Hello world!" for the given request, but as the aspect is being ignored, it just returns "Hello".

To make sure that the `@Aspect` is being read, I've added an `@Around` and it's working as expected. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something to make `@DeclareMixin` works, but unfortunately I couldn't find any solution. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that `@DeclareMixin` is a native AspectJ annotation which AFAIK is unavailable in Spring AOP? If you want to use it, you ought to configure your project to use the AspectJ weaving agent. At first glance, I do not see any of the necessary configuration in your Gradle project.

Comment: @kriegaex I've read about it in a couple of answers here and I couldn't find a solution, that's the reason I've posted this with a project. I've added `org.aspectj:aspectjweaver` but it didn't made any difference. What's missing to setup in the project to make it work? Can you please help me on that? Thanks

Comment: Adding a dependency does not make the application use an agent. For that, you need `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar` on your Java command line. This is described both in the Spring manual and in the AspectJ manual as well as in dozens of answers here on SO, many of which I wrote myself. Did you read any documentation before asking here? This is not a Gradle problem, it seems to be a lack of effort one. Show me in your repository that at least you tried something in your build configuration, then I can help you solve the problem.